# Ionic Navigation side bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have problem removing an animation to my ionic app. The main problem is I dont know how to disable side bar opening on screen swipe. I want my side bar just open on click the nav-icon not to open on page swipe. 
My nav code is here:

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-traveler">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-title class="heder-tabs">
        <span><a >Travel</a></span>
        <span><a >Location</a></span>
        <span><a >Networking</a></span>
      </ion-nav-title>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>


  <ion-side-menu side="right">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
         <ion-item menu-close ng-click="">
          Traveler
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="side-navigation-pinko" menu-close href="">
          <div class="pinko-nav">
            <div class="pinko-sidenav-logo">
              <img src="img/pro4travel-logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="first-three-nav-choice">Pinko</div>
          </div>  
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="">
          Club
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="">
          My Agency
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="">
          My Karma
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="">
          Notification
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="">
          Profile
        </ion-item>
         <ion-item menu-close href="">
          Settings
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find solution myself. I have just added to ion-side-menu-content an drag-content like this:

```
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
```